# Firebase phone auth don't work in .IPA files

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I use firebase phone auth in my app. When I tested app on my phone everything work correct. But when I made .IPA file and loaded it on another devices sms didn't sent. 
Why could it happened?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you configured your app with the release push settings? (Prov profile and stuff)

Comment: Yes, I did. Any other ideas?